# Make animation functions work when executing $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having issues on making this work.  I'm using JQuery 2.0 ...

I tried this but got a exception error on `ajaxStart` object.

```
$.ajax({
   //Scripts here...
}).ajaxStart(function() { 
   animationStart();  // Display the busy animation...
}).ajaxStop(function() {
   animationStop();  // Hide the busy animation...
});
```

Comment: And what was the exception error?

Comment: do you really need global ajax handlers? or is the animation only for this particular ajax request?

Comment: The animation is only for this particular ajax request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/):

**As of jQuery 1.8, the `.ajaxStart()` method should only be attached to `document`.**

```
$(document).ajaxStart(animationStart).ajaxStop(animationStop);
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with what Jason P said what's wrong with doing it like this?

```
animationStart();

$.ajax({
   ..................
   done: function() {
       animationStop();
   }
});
```

Comment: `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` are global solutions. Using your example, if you had 100 different ajax calls, you'd have to copy this code 100 times instead of defining it once.

Comment: Yes I gathered that, but in his example it doesn't make sense that he wanted it to apply to all ajax requests.

Comment: No, not all ajax requests.  Only this very 1 written ajax request.

Comment: @fletchsod That's what I said.